# Find the columnwise indices of the minimum values of a generator in Python + Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a series of generators that creates a vector such as:

```
vector = ( remainder(v, PRIME_NUMBER) for v in list_of_vectors)
```

and I want to generate a vector containing the row indices of the matrix, be created by the above generator, that contains the minimum values.

I have this so far, using numpy:

```
minv = ones(n)*PRIME_NUMBER # n is the length of each vector
min_idx = zeros(n)
for i,r in enumerate(vector):
        min_idx = argmin(vstack((r,minv)),0)*min_idx
        min_idx = [x if x>0 else i for x in min_idx]
        minv = amin(vstack((minv,r)),0)
```

Of course this is too slow (at least for my application). I wonder if there's any faster way to do that!

I was expecting to figure out a way to do it just like if I was to obtain just the min values:

```
minvalues = reduce(lambda x,y: amin(vstack((x,y)),0) , vector)
```

EDIT: 
a working example with some modifications:

```
from numpy import random, zeros, remainder

PRIME_NUMBER = 109297
dim = 100
list_of_vectors = random.rand(1000,dim)

vector = ( remainder(v, PRIME_NUMBER) for v in list_of_vectors)

min_idx = [(0,PRIME_NUMBER)]*dim
for i,r in enumerate(vector):
        min_idx = map(lambda x: (i,x[0]) if x[0]<x[1][1] else x[1] , zip(r,min_idx))
```

this code runs 50% faster than previous one, but I still think there's some room for improvements.

Comment: The costliest operation in terms of the speed of your program is `vstack()`.  When vstack is called a new object is created and the old objects are copied into it.  If this is done once or twice this is no big deal, but if done repeatedly this copying becomes very expensive.  If you preallocate the full size of `minv` that will yield the most significant performance increase.

Comment: thanks, your tips led me to this:

    for i,r in enumerate(vector):
                min_idx = map(lambda x: (i,x[0]) if x[0]<x[1][1] else x[1] , izip(r,min_idx))

could cut the processing time in half, but I'm still trying to figure a way to eliminate the for loop

Comment: could you show how does your `list_of_vectors` look like? I tried to create a list of vectors, each one containing 100 random integers to test you code, but it gives an error...

Comment: I've edited the question with a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple version of what I think you want to do that runs several times faster than your code.

```
vector = (np.remainder(v,PRIME_NUMBER) for v in list_of_vectors.T)
min_idx=[np.argmin(slice) for slice in vector)]
```

The trick is noticing that `dim << len(vector)` and thus is the right item to slice over.  You can't do this with the generator as you've defined it.

If you absolutely must use the given generator, you could do e.g. `vector=np.array([v for v in vector]).T`.  But that completely defeats the purpose of using a generator.

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention is that the "list_of_vectors" is a generator as well, so I couldn't transpose. But your answer got me thinking how to generate the transpose instead and I could reach the desired speed! Thank you!